# Should nouns used as adjectives be in plural?

Tags: adjectives, grammatical-number

In Spanish, we say "Servicio de reservas" and in English we are in doubt about these options:

- Booking**s** Service
- Booking Service
- Booking Service**s**

The problem is that we think that the first one represents what we are trying to say, but maybe it's wrong, and then no one represents exactly what we are trying to say..

Which one is the correct?

Comment: All of these are correct.  Some may be more common in one place, other in other places.

Comment: @PabloMatiasGomez In Spanish, are you describing a plural noun or a singular noun? If plural it would be booking services. If Singular it would be booking service. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think there's any simple or consistently-observed "plurality rule" here. For example, it's usually a *[Concert] **Booking** Service*, but a *[University] **Admissions** Officer*.

Comment: @anonymous It is plural, but for "Reservas", so it may be plural for "bookings". If you say "booking services" I thinkg you are saying "Servicios de reserva" in Spanish..

Comment: You forgot Bookings Services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, there generally are not plural adjectives, but it does get a little trickier in the case of nouns as adjectives. Usually, the noun is left singular, but can be pluralized in some cases, particularly when talking about an institution or organization (e.g., Admissions Office), or when the singular would impart a different meaning (e.g., arms race).

In this case, I would go with Booking Service, or Booking Services.

See also:

http://david-crystal.blogspot.com.es/2010/05/on-plural-adjectives.html